# jQuery Advance Password Strength

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-applications, passwords

I am trying to make my jQuery Advance Password Strength script stronger by adding the following code. But somehow it is not working.

If the title `div` has "Document", the file would be called "Document.txt".

My problem is that I want it to also upload a file and take its file name.

Here is the code:

```
function check_pass() {

    var pass_length = $("#regpass").val().length;

    if(pass_length < 8) {
        $("#pass_error").html("more than 8");
        $("#pass_error").show();
        error_pass = true;
    } else {
        $("#pass_error").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: and its take me to the other page without any secure even if i add firebase!!!!!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.